# Writing into a JSON (Node for Discord.JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I wrote a command that is supposed to change a prefix by the new one the user specified.
My prefix is written in a file named "config.json" that can be found at the root of my project.

My command, in a file named "setprefix.js" and located in the "commands" folder, is the following :

```
const config = require('../config.json')
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = {
    run: async (message, args) => {
        if(!message.author === config.ownerID) return message.channel.send("Only the owner can change the prefix!");
        if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Please specify the new prefix !")
        config.prefix = args[0];
        await fs.writeFile('../config.json', JSON.stringify(config), (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
        });
        console.log(config.prefix)
    },
    name: 'setprefix',
    help: {
        description: 'Changes server prefix',
        syntax: '<new prefix>'
    }
}
```

no callback so no error triggered, but still no changes in my config.json file.
I've also tried the writeFileSync variant with no success
Code is reached and config.prefix is set with the right informations

Could you please help me, I must have been missing something but I sincerely don't understand what I'm doing wrong

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your file may not be writing to the proper path, as it depends on where the script is executing from.

you can try replacing your path with below, this way it'll return the name of dir of where your executing script is in.

```
 await fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, '../config.json'), JSON.stringify(config), (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While I get your point, I don't get what "path" variable is supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarification. It's a built-in nodejs module with a handful of helpful path related methods. path.join(path1, path2) will simply join the 2 paths for you, which will do essentially what you did in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong.
Thanks to ayoshi for helping me looking the right way.

So writeFile wasn't looking for the right file (apparently).

Instead of using relative path I used this and worked just fine :

```
fs.writeFileSync(__dirname+'/../config.json', JSON.stringify(config), (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
        });
```